# Email notification whenever there's any change to a view-only Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, notifications

I have view-only access to a Google Sheet. Is there any way I can set up an email notification whenever there is any change to this Google Sheet?

(Right now, Tools > Notification Rules is greyed-out.)

Answer (score 1):

No, there definitively isn't such a possibility if you have view-only access. The workaround would be to use **`IMPORTRANGE`** formula to import the whole sheet into your spreadsheet and then set up an email notification based on changes of your sheet. Note that due to **`IMPORTRANGE`** limitations you could experience up to a half hour delays.

Answer (score -1):

Try this, it may help you:

1. On your computer, open a spreadsheet in Google Sheets.
2. At the top, click Tools and then Notification rules.
3. In the window that appears, select "how often" you want to receive 
   notifications.
4. Notify you with:
   Email - daily digest: Send a daily summary of all changes.
   Email - right away: Send an email for every change.
5. Click Save.

Comment: The OP mentioned that the Notifications menu is greyed out (not available).